# Is it possible to write Lagrangian mechanics for a catenary curve?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

A catenary is formed when a rope or chain hangs freely in the effect of gravity supported by two ends. The shape is a result of optimisation of potential energy along the length of the rope. This kind of curve is generally represented in a static case in equilibrium.

What happens when the supporting ends move (maybe slowly)? I believe now that more kinetic energy is added to the system. Can the equations of motion of points along a catenary be derived based on minimization of potential energy and kinetic energy ? Can this kind of formulation work for describing a motion of any point in a catenary ? I would like to know your suggestions and views on this fascinating problem and approach.

Comment: Actually, you can sweep the technicalities under the carpet by allowing the boundaries of the same action functional to be time-dependent, i.e. $S = \int_{x_1(t)}^{x_2(t)} \mathcal{L} \,\mathrm{d}x$, with $\mathcal{L} = (\rho g + \lambda)\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}$, where $\rho$ is a linear density and $\lambda$ is a Lagrangian multiplier due to the fixed length constraint. Then, those time-dependent boundaries will intervene when extremizing the action. Here is shown how to carry such computations : https://tetraquark.netlify.app/post/catenary/#one_end_sliding